# Representing Infinite Domains in Prolog

Tags: prolog

How is it possible to represent infinite domains in Prolog? I have been searching this topic for a while, but do not have a clue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: specific example please.

Comment: Suppose we want to represent generating IDs for people, and this could be infinite as over time there will be infinite people who need IDs. Or any other contexts where we need to have infinite objects.